Add information from custom checkout fields in Dokan / Woocommerce sub orders
I need to add some information about custom checkout fields in suborders that are received by sellers in the admin panel and by email.
For normal requests I use the following code and it works:
//Add the CPF and CNPJ on the Seller's Order page
function display_cpf_order_dokan( $order ) {
    
    echo '<strong>Informações do cliente</strong>';

    if ($order->billing_cpf){
        echo '<br><p> <strong>CPF: </strong>'. $order->billing_cpf.'</p>';
    } 
    if ($order->billing_cnpj){ 
        echo '<br><strong>CNPJ: </strong>'. $order->billing_cnpj. '<br/>';
    }
    if ($order->billing_ie){ 
        echo '<strong>Inscrição estadual: </strong>'. $order->billing_ie. '<br/>';
    }
    if ($order->billing_company){ 
        echo '<strong>Razão social: </strong>'. $order->billing_company. '<br/><br/>';
    } 
 
}
add_action('dokan_order_detail_after_order_items', 'display_cpf_order_dokan', 30, 3 );

//Add the CPF and CNPJ in the seller's email
function brazilian_market_on_wooCommerce_display_email_order_user_meta( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ) {
 
    if ($order->billing_cpf){
        echo '<br><p> <strong>CPF: </strong>'. $order->billing_cpf.'<br/>';
    } 
    if ($order->billing_cnpj){ 
        echo '<br><p> <strong>CNPJ: </strong>'. $order->billing_cnpj. '<br/>';
    }
    if ($order->billing_ie){ 
        echo '<strong>Inscrição estadual: </strong>'. $order->billing_ie. '<br/>';
    }
    if ($order->billing_company){ 
        echo '<strong>Razão social: </strong>'. $order->billing_company. '<br/><br/>';
    } 
 
}
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'brazilian_market_on_wooCommerce_display_email_order_user_meta', 30, 3 );

However, for sub orders this code does not work.
I thank the attention.
I need to take this data that is displayed in orders and emails and also display it in sub-orders and sub-order emails from suppliers.
